# uploading multiple files of the same field having diffrent categories using multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am using node express and multer for single file uploads which are working fine!

I am new to multer. And I am posting an array something like this:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "images": Array [
      Object {
        "name": "download.jpeg",
        "type": "image/jpg",
        "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540asxce%252Fvenuefy/ImageManipulator/a7175dfe-e5b2-4a01-841a-4ef2b6b79778.jpg",        
      },
      Object {
        "name": "images (1).jpeg",
        "type": "image/jpg",
        "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540asxce%252Fvenuefy/ImageManipulator/9795f940-5b9c-4653-96bd-cb445ff0e735.jpg",        
      },
    ],
    "title": "Bedroom",
  },
 Object {
    "images": Array [
      Object {
        "name": "download.jpeg",
        "type": "image/jpg",
        "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540asxce%252Fvenuefy/ImageManipulator/a7175dfe-e5b2-4a01-841a-4ef2b6b79778.jpg",        
      },
      Object {
        "name": "images (1).jpeg",
        "type": "image/jpg",
        "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540asxce%252Fvenuefy/ImageManipulator/9795f940-5b9c-4653-96bd-cb445ff0e735.jpg",        
      },
    ],
    "title": "Living Room",
  },
]
```

Basically it's a Library field with nested categories "Bedroom" and "Living Room". Each category having their own photos.

Multer only gives options for Fileds and Array. Can anyone please help me understand how can i handle complex uploads like this with multer?

Answer (score 1):

i don't think there is much of a choice here. you should send the nested categories bedroom etc seperately instead of nesting them and then use `.field` method to specify the path and count. in this way it will be more manageable.

```
upload.fields([
  {
    name: 'bedroom',
    maxCount: 100,
  },
  {
    name: 'livingRoom',
    maxCount: 100,
  },
  ...
]);
```

Comment: You are right it makes sense! But the problem is that these categories are user input those are generated dynamically. Any solution for that?